# function argument in register

Tags: gcc, arm

Is there a way to disable passing function arguments in registers using gcc 3.3.1 for ARM?

Comment: Not that I know of.  But it's gcc - if you're willing to do a little work, you can modify the source.  Not for the uninitiated though.

You are aware that this will cause your code to violate the ARM EABI (embedded application binary interface), right?

Comment: +1 @Dan.  Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I've run into a similar situation. My issue is that I'm passing several struct parameters to an asm function. Half of the first struct winds up in r3, and everything else is on the stack. It's much more convenient if all of the structs are the same (i.e. on the stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I see dwelch gave a global answer, but if you'd like to do this on a function by function basis then use the gcc `__attribute__` with `regparm`.  iirc, it should look like this:

```
int __attribute__((regparm(0))) function(int a, char b) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these options is what you are looking for

```
-mabi=name
Generate code for the specified ABI. Permissible values are: `apcs-gnu', `atpcs', `aapcs', `aapcs-linux' and `iwmmxt'.
```

if not, and if there is anything it, would probably be a compile time option (when gcc is compiled).

Comment: Those are just small variants of the base ABI. They all pass the first 4 32bit values in registers.